# Working on 2 pc - synchronization

Tags: mysql, apache, synchronization

I'm web developer and I use Apache installed on my PC. Recently I bought a new laptop. I would like to work on 2 computers. Usually, when I am at home, on PC, but sometimes, when I'im out on laptop.

I have a problem with synchronization of these 2 computers, specifically apache htdocs and mysql.

I was thinking about virtual machine but it is really complicated. My second idea was synchronization htadocs by dropbox, but it doesn't solve problem of mysql.

Did anyone has similar problem? What solution would be the best in your opinion?

Comment: do not understand .. u need to synchronize mysql & what? apache?

Comment: Assumptions can be made that the OP wants files and db synced between multiple machines. @Mariusz, it might be a better idea to put your MySQL database on a hosted server somewhere, saves having to back it up on one machine and import it on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wamp?

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: And what about the OP's issue of syncing MySQL?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP. What is the difference between XAMPP and WAMP?

Comment: With a program such as either, shouldn't you be able to share the files for the server with each other through the network?

Comment: Hmm where can I found that option?

Answer (score 0):

1. for mysql synchronization simple solution is a dump. i use [Sypex Dumper](http://sypex.net/) witch allow to create tasks and even call them through command line.
2. for files may be svn be a good one. (to not lost information when both edited files)